# CNN channel mistake

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make CNN that looks like this:

```py
class CNNBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(3, 32, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool3d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 14 * 14 , 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 14 * 14)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

to try and train in on the CIFAR10 dataset.

I get the error:

```
Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 128, 3, 32, 32] to have 3 channels, but got 128 channels instead
```

anybody knows why?

thx

Comment: There is a problem with dataloader. Check the dataloader output. Better to share dataloading code also.

Comment: why are you using `conv3d` for CIFAR? CIFAR is 2D images.